# Trying to create XML with namespaces using PHP and DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am attempting to create an XML file using PHP 5.6.24 and DOMDocument. The format of the XML is supposed to be as follows:

```
<parks xmlns:tch="{urn}" xmlns:prk="{urn}">
```

It is my understanding that the following block of code:

```
$root = $doc->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 'element');
$doc->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$item = $doc->createElementNS('http://base.google.com/ns/1.0', 'g:item_type', 'house');
$root->appendChild($item);
```

Will allow me to produce the following output:

```
<element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <g:item_type>house</g:item_type>
</element>
```

The problem with this is that this method only allows me to add **one** tagname as opposed to the **two** that I need (tch and prk).

Is it possible to achieve this result using the DOMDocument library or is there something better for this situation.

Thank you in advanced!!!!!!

Comment: Guess you can always use this: http://de1.php.net/manual/de/domelement.setattributens.php

Comment: This is a bit confusing as your attempt does not align to desired result. Why are you creating an *element* tag with *item_type* child when you want a *parks* tag with no child? Please advise on true end goal.

Comment: I am sorry the code and output were from the DOMDocument documentation. I just posted it as an example. The xml above with parks is the output that I actually want  to build.

Comment: Is that all the XML you intend to output or only the root tag? As of now, it is not a well-formed XML which DOMDocument will generate.

Comment: It is only a portion, I am more concerned with learning the proper way to deal with namespaces in this situation.